# Window.settimeout failing when using firefox 27.0.1

Tags: javascript, lotus-notes

I'm getting this error: "TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.setTimeout is not an object." with the code below.  It works ok in other browsers and earlier versions of Firefox.  Any ideas?

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=JAVASCRIPT>
window.setTimeout("Advance()", 0, "JAVASCRIPT");
function Advance()
{
location.replace('iWelcome');
}
</SCRIPT>
```

thanks
clem

Comment: what does "JAVASCRIPT" do for you?

Comment: Why the lotus-notes tag? What's the connection?

Comment: It's actually a page redirection in a form.  Depending on whether the person who clicked the link is a customer or not, the specific page gets displayed.  The function is actually:   function Advance()
{
location.replace('<Computed Value>');
}  and the 'computed value' is "@If( @Contains( @UserRoles; "Customer" ); "cWelcome"; "iWelcome" )"

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why they made the change, but it appears that now when you pass the extra arguments to `setTimeout`, it'll throw an error if you've provided a string instead of a function for the first argument.

This makes sense, since there would be no way for them to pass `"JAVASCRIPT"` into `"Advance()"`, unless they tried to parse the string.

---

To fix it, either remove the `"JAVASCRIPT"` argument (since you're not using it anyway):

```
setTimeout("Advance()", 0);
```

or pass a function, which is a better idea in any case.

```
setTimeout(function(x) {
    Advance(x);
}, 0, "JAVASCRIPT");
```

---

Or I guess you could code the `"JAVASCRIPT"` into the call directly if indeed you're using it, and insist on passing a string.

```
setTimeout("Advance(\"JAVASCRIPT\")", 0);
```

Comment: thanks.  That was all it was -- the "JAVASCRIPT" argument.  I snagged this code from somewhere and have been using it for years and it just now broke.  I got thrown by the error msg: "argument 1" was the problem, it said.  Thanks! :-)